# Создание экземпляров класса в цикле

Tags: objective-c

Можно это заменить циклом ?

```
Animal* leon = [[Leon alloc]init];
Animal* zebra = [[Zebra alloc]init];
Animal* kenguru = [[Kenguru alloc]init];
Animal* mouse = [[Mouse alloc]init];
Animal* penguin = [[Penguin alloc]init];
```

Comment: Наверное да, если положить в массив идентификаторы классов, а потом перебирать элементы массива и на каждом делать что-то вроде `element.instanceOf()` (как-то так в Java, но похожий синтаксис должен быть и в Obj-C). Но зачем это? Вы сделаете код гораздо менее понятным.

Comment: Чтобы не в ручную создавать и инициализировать >100 экземпляров, а прогнать циклом.

Comment: у вас там >100 экземпляров **разных** классов вроде Leon, Zebra и т.п.? Или я просто синтаксис неправильно понял?

Comment: Все верно, разных классов.

Comment: если у вас их там под сотню, зачем вам иметь для них отдельные переменные, не проще ли засунуть в массив?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если хранить все объекты в массиве подходит, то можно сделать так

```
NSArray *listOfAnimals = @[@"Zebra", @"Penguin"];
NSMutableArray *listOfAnimalInstances = [NSMutableArray new];
for(int i = 0; i<listOfAnimals.count; i++) {
    [listOfAnimalInstances addObject:[NSClassFromString(listOfAnimals[i]) new]];
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! То что нужно!